# AudioContext does not have a pause property?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, audiocontext, webkitaudiocontext

I have used javascript `Audio()` before, but now I need to add some reverb effect in the audio and I am using reverb.js which uses the AudioContext api. I have the start property available, but no pause property? How do I pause or stop the audio??

Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://reverbjs.org/reverb.js"></script>
<script>
// 1) Setup your audio context (once) and extend with Reverb.js.
var audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
reverbjs.extend(audioContext);

// 2) Load the impulse response; upon load, connect it to the audio output.
var reverbUrl = "http://reverbjs.org/Library/SaintLawrenceChurchMolenbeekWersbeekBelgium.m4a";
var reverbNode = audioContext.createReverbFromUrl(reverbUrl, function() {
  reverbNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
});

// 3) Load a test sound; upon load, connect it to the reverb node.
var sourceUrl = "./sample.mp3";
var sourceNode = audioContext.createSourceFromUrl(sourceUrl, function() {
  sourceNode.connect(reverbNode);
});
</script>
<a href="javascript:sourceNode.start()">Play</a>
<a href="javascript:sourceNode.stop()">Stop</a>
```

Also, I tried using `stop()`, and it works, but when I fire `start()` after clicking on stop, the `start()` doesn't work. Can you you help me out with a solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `suspend()` and `resume()` methods of `AudioContext` to pause and resume your audio: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/suspend

One way to implement this with a single button for play/pause/resume, would be to add a function that controls the player state. For example:

```
let started = false;
function pauseOrResume() {
    if (!started) {
        sourceNode.start();
        started = true;
        document.getElementById("pauseButton").innerHTML = 'Pause';
    } else if (audioContext.state === 'running') {
        audioContext.suspend().then(function () {
            document.getElementById("pauseButton").innerHTML = 'Resume';
        });
    } else if (audioContext.state === 'suspended') {
        audioContext.resume().then(function () {
            document.getElementById("pauseButton").innerHTML = 'Pause';
        });
    }
}
```

And replace your existing "Play" button with:

```
<a id="pauseButton" href="javascript:pauseOrResume()">Play</a>
```

This does the following:

- If the audio hasn't yet been started, the link will say "Play".
- If the user clicks "Play", the audio will start playing and the text of the link will change to "Pause".
- If the user clicks "Pause" while the audio is playing, it will be paused, and the text of the link will change to "Resume".

Comment: Thanks mate!! I'll try this and let you know :)

Comment: Hey, what can I do if I don't want to resume it, but start it again from time 0??

Comment: A source created from `createBufferSource()` can only be played once. Once you stop it, you have to create a new one. So you could create a function that creates a new `sourceNode` when you want to restart the audio from the beginning. Take a look at the example on [this page](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/). You'll see they created a `playSound` function that creates a new sourceNode whenever the play button is clicked.